# Screen black out issue with JASidePanel

Tags: ios, objective-c, jasidepanels

I tried to integrate the [JASidePanel](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) in my app. Below is my code for initialising JSSidePanel controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
    UIWindow *window= [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    self.viewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;
    self.viewController.leftPanel = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BBWSideMenuViewController"];
    self.viewController.centerPanel = [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];

    window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Button Action method,

```
- (IBAction)openSideMenu:(id)sender {
     [self.viewController showLeftPanelAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I'm pressing button to open side menu, entire screen is getting black. How may i fix this?. Any Help will be much appreciated.